# Notepad++ Multiply all px references by X?

Tags: javascript, html, replace, notepad++

I have a html image map with over 3000 lines of images with top/left px positions.
I'm wanting to use larger images which means increasing all of the px references by X amount.

I'm not very good with scripting though.
Is there a way to do this in Notepad++ or alternative editor?
Or an easy script I can run on the file?

They are the only numbers in the file, and all of them need multiplying by the same number (except where it's 0px)

Comment: "except where it's 0px" -- FYI, it would be safe to do this, so no need to check the value....

Comment: I always recommend using Sublime Text: http://www.sublimetext.com/3

Comment: Are there multiple numbers on a single line? Or does each number have its own line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I always do when I need to perform more complicated find&replace tasks is just pasting the contents of the file into a simple `<textarea>`, assigning an ID to it, and performing a JS find&replace.

The script I'd use would just use a simple JavaScript `String.replace` with a callback function:

```
window.factor = parseInt(prompt('Which factor should the values be multiplied with?','1'));
if (factor) {
    var input = document.getElementById('textinput');
    input.value = input.value.replace(/[0-9]+/g, function(match) {
        return (parseInt(match) * window.factor);
    });
}
```

I've made a working example of the script **[here](http://jsbin.com/UNENaXUp/1/)**. I hope that works for you. PS: this script will show a prompt window asking you for the factor you want to multiply with when you run it (in the demo you run it by pressing the button).

Comment: This is great! So simple and doesn't require any plug-ins or other software. To think I almost tried scripting something up in Excel for OP... lol

Comment: This is neat, but I noticed this multiplies **any number**. Here's a quick fix to only apply to "px" values: http://jsbin.com/OSAkaTe/1

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks :)
Thankfully none of my file names have numbers in. Would it be easy enough to exclude anything with src="*" though?

Edit: Nvm... above comment solves that.

Answer (score 0):

You could run a script along the lines of this:

```
$(function() {
    $.get('numbers.txt', function(data) {
        $.each(data, function() {
            // Multiply
            // Put back into a new text file
        });
    });
});
```

This will of course require that both the text file and the script are on a server, as the `$.get` method [accesses a URL](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/).